Module Not Found Error- Local Streamlit app
I've been working on a project to a create a chatbot like app using langchain and streamlit for UI. but whenever I'm trying to run the app I keep getting this error:
(venv) D:\Gen AI projs\Code Analyzer>python main.py 
Starting the AI Code Analyzer...
INFO:root:Starting Streamlit app...

You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

Local URL: http://localhost:8501
Network URL: http://192.168.1.10:8501

2024-12-25 15:26:00.496 Uncaught app execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Gen AI projs\Code Analyzer\venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\exec_code.py", line 88, in exec_func_with_error_handling
    result = func()
             ^^^^^^
  File "D:\Gen AI projs\Code Analyzer\venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 579, in code_to_exec    
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "D:\Gen AI projs\Code Analyzer\ui\streamlit_ui.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.model_loader import load_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

My directory structure looks like this:

And the code in each file is as follows:

main.py:

import os
import sys
import subprocess
import logging
# Add project root to PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def start_streamlit():
    """Starts the Streamlit application."""
    try:
        logging.info("Starting Streamlit app...")
        subprocess.run(["streamlit", "run", "ui/streamlit_ui.py"])
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error starting Streamlit app: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting the AI Code Analyzer...")
    start_streamlit()

ui/streamlit_ui.py:
import streamlit as st
import os
import sys
from app.model_loader import load_model
from app.analyzer import analyze_code
print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())
# Dynamically add the root directory to PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))
print("SRC Directory exists:", os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "src")))


# Load the model once when the app starts
st.title("AI Code Analyzer")
tokenizer, model = load_model()

# User inputs code for analysis
user_code = st.text_area("Enter your code:", height=300)

if st.button("Analyze Code"):
    if not user_code.strip():
        st.error("Please enter some code to analyze.")
    else:
        with st.spinner("Analyzing code..."):
            try:
                result = analyze_code(user_code, tokenizer, model)
                st.success("Analysis Complete!")
                st.text_area("Analysis Result:", value=result, height=300, disabled=True)
            except Exception as e:
                st.error(f"Analysis failed: {e}")

app/model_loader.py:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

def load_model():
    """Loads the StarCoder model and tokenizer."""
    model_name = "bigcode/starcoderbase"
    try:
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, device_map="auto", torch_dtype="float16")
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to load model: {e}")
    return tokenizer, model

app/analyzer.py:
import langdetect  # You may need to install this package

def analyze_code(code: str, tokenizer, model, language: str = None) -> str:
    """
    Analyze the code using the model for errors, security vulnerabilities, and optimizations.
    The function generates a detailed analysis of the code in bullet points.
    """
    # Detect language if not provided
    if not language:
        language = langdetect.detect(code)
    
    # If a language is provided, include it in the prompt
    language_info = f" in {language}" if language else ""
    
    input_prompt = (
        f"Analyze the following code{language_info}:\n\n"
        f"{code}\n\n"
        f"1. Detect syntax or logical errors.\n"
        f"2. Identify security vulnerabilities.\n"
        f"3. Suggest optimizations or best practices.\n"
        f"Provide detailed feedback in bullet points."
    )

    try:
        # Tokenizing the input prompt
        inputs = tokenizer(input_prompt, return_tensors="pt")
        # Generating output using the model
        outputs = model.generate(inputs.input_ids, max_length=512, num_return_sequences=1)
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Error during analysis: {e}")

    # Decoding the response
    response = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    return response


requirements.txt:
streamlit
langchain 
transformers 
torch
langdetect

How to resolve this problem?

This is not a streamlit dependency problem, but a working directory problem. When you start the main.py, you are looking at the whole project. However, when you run the subprocess from the main file, the python environment that allows you to run the streamlit_ui python scripts is changed.
There are some solutions you can adopt:

You can run the application using PYTHONPATH=.:
PYTHONPATH=. python main.py

Assuming you are in the root of the project.

PYTHONPATH is an environment variable used by the Python interpreter to determine where to locate the module files imported into a program. It's part of the larger concept of environment variables, which provide a way to influence the behavior of software on a computer.


You can add the environment code-side using the getcwd function:
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = os.getcwd()



Finally, I suggest that you use the check=True parameter in the subprocess.run() function to ensure that an error is raised if the streamlit command fails. If the command exits with a non-zero status, subprocess.CalledProcessError will be thrown.
def start_streamlit():
    """Starts the Streamlit application."""
    try:
        logging.info("Starting Streamlit app...")

        # (one of the possible solutions)
        # Setting PYTHONPATH to the current working directory
        os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = os.getcwd()

        subprocess.run(["streamlit", "run", "ui/streamlit_ui.py"], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        # Logging the specific error if the Streamlit command fails
        logging.error(f"Streamlit command failed with error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        # Logging any other errors that might occur
        logging.error(f"Error starting Streamlit app: {e}")



subprocess.CalledProcessError if the streamlit command fails, this exception will be caught, and the error message will be logged.
Exception a more generic catch-all for any other exceptions that might occur, ensuring they are also logged.

See more here:

subprocess.run
subprocess.CalledProcessError


The streamlit command in main.py runs the script in a new process, which doesn't inherit the modified sys.path from main.py.
You can modify the PYTHONPATH environment variable directly in the subprocess.run call within main.py. Here is how you can do it:
def start_streamlit():
    try:
        logging.info("Starting Streamlit app...")
        env = os.environ.copy()
        env["PYTHONPATH"] = os.pathsep.join(sys.path)
        subprocess.run(["streamlit", "run", "ui/streamlit_ui.py"], check=True, env=env)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error starting Streamlit app: {e}")

I tested this and it is working fine without any error. Also, you don't have to handle the path in streamlit_ui.py file. Doing it in main.py file should be sufficient.
